# What's the proper way to use mesh operators in python when running blender from the command line?

Tags: modeling, python, command-line

I need to do a loop cut on a mesh I've generated, so I found some code that works when I run Blender normally then the script.  The catch is, I need it to work when I launch Blender from the command line and currently it causes an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION that crashes blender :(

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = argObject
        argObject.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        
        # setup a bunch of context for the loop cut operation
        region, rv3d, v3d, area = self.view3d_find(True)
        override = {
            'scene' : bpy.context.scene,
            'region': region,
            'area':area,
            'space':v3d
        }
        
        # perform the loop cut operation
        bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
            override,
            MESH_OT_loopcut = {
                "number_cuts":loopNumber,
                "smoothness":0,
                "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE',
                "object_index": 0,
                "edge_index": 2,
                "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)
            },
            TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide = {
                "value": 0,
                "mirror": False,
                "snap": False,
                "snap_target": 'CLOSEST',
                "snap_point": (0,0,0),
                "snap_align": False,
                "snap_normal": (0,0,0),
                "correct_uv": False,
                "release_confirm": False,
                "use_accurate": False
            }
        )
```

Here's the error message I get in the command line:

Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF7193BE4C3
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00007ec0
Writing: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\MyBlend.crash.txt

I had a look in the crash log above for a thread with the id listed, but there was none :/

Comment: not sure why you have different properties in your override (like scene and space). but try to use these four (4) properties: window, screen, area, region as shown in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270716/142292 . This one makes your code work.

Comment: use `override ={'window':bpy.context.window,'screen':bpy.context.window.screen,'area':area,'region': region}`. and try to `print(type(area), type(region))` and make sure they really are classes `bpy.types.Area` and `bpy.types.Region`

Comment: and kindly share a link of your `crash.txt` log or paste the last few lines of the error in that crash.txt log.

Comment: Hey Harry,

Thanks for all your help :)

Unfortunately, after making the changes it's still crashing :/

```region = <bpy_struct, Region at 0x0000021813BF17C8>


area = <bpy_struct, Area at 0x0000021813C0AE08>


Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION


Address : 0x00007FF7193BE4C3


Module  : blender.exe


Thread  : 0000307c


Writing: C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\SituVanity.crash.txt```

Comment: may I know how you run the script? from the Text Editor in blender or directly from the terminal or command line? and what is the command your running? please also share the crash.txt log

Comment: It won't let me post more than a couple of lines sorry, and the comments don't seem to "support" line breaks (???)

Is there a way to add the crash log as a file?

Comment: use http://pastie.org/ and paste the log there then share the link it generates

Comment: fwiw, here's the line from the batch file that calls blender:

"Bin\blender-3.2.1-windows-x64\blender" -b Blends\Vanity.blend -P Scripts\RenderParametricVanity.py -- --cycles-device OPTIX --vanityConfig marquis_bay_wall_1200 --themeConfig florentine_walnut --outputPath ..\Output --optionsConfigFilePath Data\Company\Configs\Options\ExampleOptions01.json

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/1LcRediuQz7jkurZXjxNRF

Comment: Is there another way to do a loopcut apart from bpy.ops?
I noticed you said in the other post it's best to avoid bpy.ops...

Comment: ok so i see it is in `Scripts\Parametric\box.py", line 215 in addVerticalBanding`, are the contents exactly that snippet you posted in the question? so if you just do a pass inside the function `addVerticalBanding` will it still crash?

Comment: There's other bits around it, but if I remove the bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide command it runs without crashing

Comment: try to see if this one helps, the other answer does not use bpy.ops https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196367/how-to-use-loopcut-slide-operation-without-any-ui

Comment: Awesome, I reckon that'll do it!
I'll let you know how I go...

Comment: Awesome work Harry, it's going :)

Comment: awesome! happy it worked out for you! feel free to post the answer and i will upvote :)